# How to join the last 2 integers in python?

Tags: python, list, integer

I have a list:

> [1, 43, 2, 3]

And I want to join the last 2 integers into 1 integer to get:

> [1, 43, 23]

How can I do this?

Comment: The solution to this question has more components than simply concatenating two integers, so closing it due to it being a duplicate is not justified.

Comment: @ksbg The interesting part of the question is a duplicate. If there is more that OP doesn't understand about how to solve the problem, then a) it needs to be asked explicitly; b) it makes the question "needs more focus" and still eligible for closure.

Answer (score -1):

you can do like this:

```
numbers = [1, 43, 2, 3]
a = int("".join(str(numbers[-2])+str(numbers[-1])))
del numbers[-2]
numbers[-1] = a

print(numbers)
```